# Is there any way better than use App\Entity\ as E

Tags: php, namespaces, entity

I want to know if is any way to load all entities at once without needing to load one by one, because for a project like I'm having more than 20 entities, it turns out to be a bit of a waste of time to write all the amounts and even a lot of code needed on the page is too large to declare.

For example, the head of my file looks like this:

```
<?php

    namespace App\DataFixtures;

    use App\Entity\Food;
    use App\Entity\Goal;
    use App\Entity\Loan;
    use App\Entity\Daily;
    use App\Entity\Health;
    use App\Entity\Monthly;
    use App\Entity\FoodType;
    use App\Entity\LoanType;
    use App\Entity\Reminder;
    use App\Entity\DailyType;
    use App\Entity\Medicines;
    use App\Entity\HealthType;
    use App\Entity\MonthlyType;
    use App\Entity\TuitionFees;
    use App\Entity\ReminderType;
    use App\Entity\MedicinesName;
    use App\Entity\ReceiveMonthly;
    use App\Entity\TuitionFeesType;
    use App\Entity\HouseholdExpenses;
    use App\Entity\ReceiveMonthlyType;
    use App\Entity\HouseholdExpensesType;
```

And I want to know if exists any way better than this:

```
<?php

    namespace App\DataFixtures;

    use App\Entity\ as E;



    $test = new E\Food();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are using PHP 7 then you can group use statements as follows `use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};` otherwise the answer is no, the methods you described are the only way

Comment: I'm using Php 7.2 I'm actually working on Symfony4. If the method you are showing is like http://3v4l.org/5MCAR @LawrenceCherone says "most code quality linters won't like it".

Comment: Well I guess it depends where your priorities lie then, I'm sure you could add an exception to your linter to ignore it (after all it is perfectly valid) or go with one of your solutions.

Comment: Anyway, your way make me write more than just using use App\Entity as E;

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class Food {
    public function hello() {
        print('Hello World!');
    }
}

function E($class, ...$params) {
    $class = 'App\\Entity\\' . $class;
    return new $class(...$params);
}

$food = E('Food');

$food->hello();
```

Comment: So that means if I want to create that would be  $food = E('food'); instead of $food = new E\Food();?

Comment: Check the last 2 rows of the code, I already included an example on how to create an instance of App\Entity\Food:

`$food = E('Food');

$food->hello();`